# Large size is not honoured when inserting image

Tags: images

Is there an image bug in WP 4.4.2? I have tried the forums but no-one replies there.

When I upload an image, it is crunched according to my media settings. But when I go to 'Add media' and select 'Large' from the dropdown, it shows and inserts an image with width=640px, though it uses the crunched image that is 1140px wide - which incidently is my Large size. 640px I have not set anywhere. Does anyone know what is going on? I have deactivated all plugins before upload, and tried in 2015 and Underscores themes.

[image]

Comment: That does look bugged. Have you tried disabling plugins / core theme to check that nothing is messing with it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload a featured image/a thumbnail for a post? If that's the case, then it will have to be resized like that.

If you are not, try clicking on the 'Edit Image' option on the 'Insert Media' section and try messing around with the settings there.

Regards,
CSCoder.

Comment: No it's not a featured image/post thumbnail - just using the plain "add media" button above the editor. I begin to think there is something that I am _seriously misunderstanding_ when it comes to the _large size_ image and how it is supposed to be used. Why do I specify a large size in "Media settings" if I can't choose this size when adding media? The size offered for _Large_ appears to change according to theme (tested 2013, 2014 and 2015) - am I supposed to tell my theme what width/height to use for large (keeping in mind that thumbnail and medium works automatically)?

Comment: I found:[link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages) that says: _Large: Displays a large-sized version of your image on the page/post. Note: WordPress will determine the width of the content column of your theme, and display the largest possible image for that space._ Testing with theme 2015 is saw the content column was exactly the width of the Large file in the dropdown (604px). Eureka! However, after changing the CSS to make this column wider (800px), the image width proposed for large is still the same. How does WP "determine the size" of the content column?

Answer (score 0):

`$content_width` function in functions.php.